# Singular fit for model and want to retain random intercept

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, model-selection, singular-matrix

I've read many posts about singular fit issues and this: https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#singular-models-random-effect-variances-estimated-as-zero-or-correlations-estimated-as---1 , however I've seen that most of the advice revolves around simplifying random effects. In my case I have just one random intercept that I believe is necessary based on the experimental design so I'm not sure what the best way to proceed is.
I am looking at success on a task where the outcome is binary 1=solved, 0= not solved and how other variables contribute to success. I have 13 subjects that each have 10-12 trials so I believe it's important to have the individual as a random intercept when modeling success. The other variables are summarized here:

- Sex- categorical, 2 levels
- Zoo- categorical, 2 different zoos
- Age- continuous
- Persistence- continuous, proportion of total time engaged with task per trial
- Neophilia- continuous, latency to approach task in very first trial
- Diversity- continuous, total number of actions employed per trial.

My full model is `newdmod<-glmer(Solved~Sex+Zoo+Age+Persistence+Neophilia+Diversity+(1|Individual),door, family=binomial)` (output below) I get a singular fit error with this model and I can see that the variance for my random intercept is almost 0. As I understand it, this would indicate that my random intercept should be removed, but due to my experimental design I think it's important to keep it in. I've also checked for collinearity of this full model and none of the fixed effects have high VIFs.

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood
  (Laplace Approximation) [glmerMod]
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: 
Solved ~ Sex + Zoo + Age + Persistence + Neophilia + Diversity +  
    (1 | Individual)
   Data: door

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
    99.7    123.7    -41.8     83.7      141 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.6817  0.0171  0.0910  0.2962  3.8144 

Random effects:
 Groups     Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 Individual (Intercept) 2.774e-18 1.665e-09
Number of obs: 149, groups:  Individual, 13

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  1.94544    1.04467   1.862 0.062568 .  
SexM         1.68561    0.72139   2.337 0.019459 *  
ZooRGZ      -1.04102    0.59511  -1.749 0.080240 .  
Age         -0.04028    0.02218  -1.816 0.069426 .  
Persistence  8.19243    1.60335   5.110 3.23e-07 ***
Neophilia   -0.03757    0.01167  -3.220 0.001283 ** 
Diversity   -0.36305    0.10136  -3.582 0.000341 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) SexM   ZooRGZ Age    Prsstn Neophl
SexM         0.053                                   
ZooRGZ      -0.275 -0.095                            
Age         -0.754 -0.219 -0.075                     
Persistence  0.108  0.356 -0.169 -0.291              
Neophilia   -0.557 -0.564 -0.081  0.689 -0.443       
Diversity   -0.508 -0.241  0.260  0.314 -0.648  0.329
optimizer (Nelder_Mead) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

Interestingly, if I remove one of the fixed variables (Zoo, the one with the highest p value) the singularity problem disappears and the random intercept has variance again.

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood
  (Laplace Approximation) [glmerMod]
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: 
Solved ~ Sex + Age + Persistence + Neophilia + Diversity + (1 |  
    Individual)
   Data: door

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   100.4    121.5    -43.2     86.4      142 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.5278  0.0165  0.0816  0.2958  3.6741 

Random effects:
 Groups     Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Individual (Intercept) 0.3006   0.5483  
Number of obs: 149, groups:  Individual, 13

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  1.60015    1.16986   1.368 0.171372    
SexM         1.64549    0.80376   2.047 0.040634 *  
Age         -0.04468    0.02510  -1.780 0.075003 .  
Persistence  7.89091    1.63103   4.838 1.31e-06 ***
Neophilia   -0.04018    0.01314  -3.058 0.002230 ** 
Diversity   -0.34100    0.10304  -3.309 0.000935 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) SexM   Age    Prsstn Neophl
SexM        -0.008                            
Age         -0.804 -0.199                     
Persistence  0.023  0.331 -0.284              
Neophilia   -0.602 -0.525  0.680 -0.435       
Diversity   -0.466 -0.223  0.323 -0.564  0.336
```

So my question is whether it is legitimate to simplify the full model by removing a fixed effect based on the p value with the justification that this variable is contributing least to variation in success? Especially since this fixes the singularity issue and given that I would like to keep the random effect. Or could my result with the full model provide enough support to argue that there is not enough individual variation so I don't have to account for repeated measures? Any and all help would be appreciated! I'm also happy to provide more information if it is helpful!

Edit: Adding GLM output for glm(Solved ~ Sex + Zoo + Age + Persistence + Neophilia + Diversity + Individual, family=binomial)

```
Call:
glm(formula = Solved ~ Sex + Zoo + Age + Persistence + Neophilia + 
    Diversity + Individual, family = binomial, data = door)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-2.42591   0.00001   0.05371   0.34488   2.72956  

Coefficients: (4 not defined because of singularities)
                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)         60.7768   114.3250   0.532  0.59499    
SexM               -43.7212    92.9102  -0.471  0.63794    
ZooRGZ             -63.5269   123.3433  -0.515  0.60652    
Age                  0.1188     0.3874   0.307  0.75917    
Persistence          7.8394     1.9450   4.031 5.56e-05 ***
Neophilia           -0.6940     1.2860  -0.540  0.58942    
Diversity           -0.3727     0.1173  -3.178  0.00148 ** 
IndividualAjay     113.6391   229.9300   0.494  0.62114    
IndividualBamboo   -65.2868   130.9487  -0.499  0.61808    
IndividualBatu      97.5497   195.7502   0.498  0.61825    
IndividualChandra  -61.2992   121.6868  -0.504  0.61444    
IndividualDoc      105.7723   207.0135   0.511  0.60939    
IndividualKandula  -15.1359    24.6599  -0.614  0.53936    
IndividualKirina    20.5416  2647.9499   0.008  0.99381    
IndividualMali      20.6377  2600.2857   0.008  0.99367    
IndividualRex            NA         NA      NA       NA    
IndividualRomani         NA         NA      NA       NA    
IndividualSiri           NA         NA      NA       NA    
IndividualTarga          NA         NA      NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 157.574  on 148  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  69.857  on 134  degrees of freedom
AIC: 99.857

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 18
```

Raw data here: https://github.com/sjacobson1112/Problem-solving/blob/main/doorsuccess.csv

Comment: Please also add the summary output of the model `glm(Solved ~ Sex + Zoo + Age + Persistence + Neophilia + Diversity + Individual, family=binomial)` Also, please explain what all the variables are.

Comment: @RobertLong I have added that information to the post, thanks!

Comment: What is the `Zoo` variable ? Also, you didn't include `Individual` in the `glm` model.

Comment: @RobertLong My apologies, should be fixed now! These are animals at two different zoos, so there are two different zoo categories.

Comment: Are all individuals tested in both Zoos, are they restricted to one or the other Zoo, or is there some mix in terms of individual associations with Zoos?

Comment: They are restricted to one or the other zoo, such that there are 5 at one zoo and 8 at the other @EdM

Comment: Can you provide a link to the dataset ?

Comment: Edited with a link to the dataset, thanks! @RobertLong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be trying to push these data a bit too far.

First, unpenalized logistic regression models typically need about 15 cases in the least-prevalent outcome class per predictor to avoid overfitting. With only 33 trials showing `Solved = 0`, you should be wary of evaluating more than 2 or 3 predictors. If you count the random-intercept effect as a single predictor, you have 7 predictors in your model. Also, of the 13 `Individual`s, 4 account for 23 of those 33 trials, 2 have no trials with `Solved = 0`, and 4 more have only 1 trial each with `Solved = 0`. Be cautious.

Second, each `Individual` has a single value of each of `Sex`, `Age`, and `Neophilia`, in addition to `Zoo`, for all trials.* Removing *any one* of those predictors from the original full mixed model removes the singularity problem. I can't say precisely why that is the case, but it presumably has to do with the ratio of the number of such predictors (4) to the number (13) of separate individuals. Perhaps once you have identified the associations of those 4 fixed predictors with outcome, there isn't much left to further associate with the `Individual`s as random effects.

The implications for your questions:

> whether it is legitimate to simplify the full model by removing a fixed effect based on the p value ...

You should be evaluating fewer predictors in any event. What you are proposing is similar to backward stepwise selection of predictors, probably the least objectionable of stepwise approaches. It would be better to use your knowledge of the subject matter to choose the most crucial fixed-effect predictors to include from the beginning.

> Or could my result with the full model provide enough support to argue that there is not enough individual variation so I don't have to account for repeated measures?

If you perform the no-`Zoo` model both with the `Individual` random effect and by completely ignoring the `Individual` values (in a `glm`), you get very different results. The magnitudes of the fixed-effect coefficients are about 10 times larger in the no-`Zoo` mixed model than in a no-`Zoo` `glm` model that omits `Individual`.  That raises red flags.

I suspect that this has to do with overfitting. For example, the fixed-effect coefficients of models restricted to `Persistence`, `Neophilia` and `Diversity` are quite similar whether `Individual` is ignored (with `glm`) or included as a random-effect intercept (with `glmer`).

Look carefully at your data and apply your knowledge of the subject matter to decide how best to proceed.

---

*That's why the last 4 coefficients for levels of `Individual` in the `glm` model without random effects are `NA`. Had you listed `Individual` as the first predictor in the model formula, then those 4 predictors would have had the NA values instead.

Comment: Thank you so much @EdM! This makes a lot of sense. Based on your feedback I will only include the crucial variables of interest for my hypotheses and take out the variables that I wanted to "control for," sex, age, and zoo. Do you think it's best to state that I pared down predictor variables due to singularity issues in a manuscript? Or something like "in order to avoid overfitting the logistic regression model, I eliminated these variables to focus on those of interest" ? It's a bit strange because I included all variables in another part of the analysis where the outcome wasn't binomial.

Comment: @Sjacobson1112 the usual rule of thumb is less stringent for continuous outcomes, about 15 _total_ cases per predictor. See section 4.4 of Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies [book](https://hbiostat.org/rms/) or [course notes](https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf). Depending on details of your other analyses, simply citing the risk of overfitting should thus be OK. If your other analyses had lower case/predictor ratios, however, they might also be overfit and you should evaluate, for example, by bootstrapping. The Harrell references point the way.

Comment: Really appreciate your help @EdM and thank you for the links to the resources!

Comment: (+1) Nice answer !! @Sjacobson1112 if this answers you question please consider marking it as a the accepted answer (and upvoting)....it's how this site works best. If not, the please let us know why  :)