# Possible to estimate random effects of a two-level factor?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, anova, lme4-nlme, multiple-comparisons

I want to conduct a two-way ANOVA with a mixed effect model using `lme4`. The trial detail is Factor A with 3 levels and Factor B with two levels (3x2) replicated on farms for two seasons. I assigned the two factors and their interaction as fixed effects, whereas farms and seasons are random factors. I tried:

```r
fit <- lmer(reponse ~ A * B + (1 | farms) + (1 | season) , data = data)
anova(fit)
```

But it is not working for me. Can you suggest better R code? Can you give more tips on pairwise comparisons?

Comment: Probably not working because you only have two seasons instead of a population of seasons from which two were randomly drawn. So start with making season fixed.

Comment: Even when you have farms and season as random effects instead of fixed effects, they might cause you to be overfitting the response.

Comment: How is it exactly not working? Can you share more details why it is not working.

Comment: A related question with overfitting is: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/628444/

Comment: Use `lmer(reponse ~ A * B * season + (1 | farms), data = data)`. Two levels of season is too small a panel size to allow random effects, and estimating seasonal differences should be insightful in farm studies.